# Using promises with Node JS express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, es6-promise

I am newbie to promises, I am trying to understand how do they work.

Here my questions at first:

1. When request is handled in a route function, does it wait for all promises, I mean that when I am using promise or callback it is a new scope and execution continues further.
2. If I keep a req/res objects for example in timer and then respond to user, what will user see ? A request will just be blocked until I explicitly send response ?

So I have encountered the following problems.

Here is my route.

```
router.post('book', authHandler.provideMiddleware(), (req, res) => {
      bookManager.createBook(req.body, {
            onSuccess: function (data) {
               respondSuccess(res,HttpStatus.OK, {'data': data});
            },
            onError: function (message) {
                respondError(res, HttpStatus.HTTP_STATUS.BAD_REQUEST, {'error': message});
            }
        });
});
```

Inside bookmanager I have the following

```
  createBook(data, hook) {
        let book = createBookFromRequest(data);
        let verifyData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let valid = checkBookData(book);
            if(valid) {
               resolve(book);
            }
            else {
                reject("Invalid data");
            }
        });
        let createBook = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            book.save((err, result) => {
                if (!err) {
                    reject("Error while saving");
                }
                else {
                    resolve(result);
                }
            });

        });
        verifyData
            .then(() => {
                return createBook;
            })
            .then((data) => {
                hook.onSuccess(data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                hook.onError(error);
            });
    }
```

My idea is to chain multiple functions and if any error occurred, call hook.onError method, otherwise call on success.

I have several problems here.

1. When error is thrown, my book is still created.
2. I have the following error

   node:8753) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 6): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

I want to use the approach like Rx (Reactive Extensions).

Could someone explain what is wrong and how do promises really work in this case ?

Comment: The code pretty much still has the same problems as in [the (your?) previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884787/using-promises-for-chaining-nodejs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. When request is handled in a route function, does it wait for all promises, I mean that when I am using promise or callback it is a new scope and execution continues further.

It waits for you to send a response via `res`. You don't have to do that in response to the event, it's absolutely normal for it to be later, after an asynchronous process (like a promise resolution) completes.

> 2. If I keep a req/res objects for example in timer and then respond to user, what will user see ? A request will just be blocked until I explicitly send response ?

Yes.

> I have several problems here.
>
> 1. When error is thrown, my book is still created.

You're **always** starting the process of creating the book, regardless of whether the data was verified as correct. `new Promise` starts the work.

> 2. I have the following error
>
> node:8753) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 6): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

You're creating a promise and storing it in `createBook`, and never handling rejections of that promise if `verifyData` rejects. So you get an unhandled promise rejection.

You can get rid of the entire `new Promise` around saving the book, and just put it in the `verifyData` chain; see comments:

```
createBook(data, hook) {
    let book = createBookFromRequest(data);
    let verifyData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let valid = checkBookData(book);
        if (valid) {
            resolve(book);
        }
        else {
            reject("Invalid data");
        }
    });
    verifyData
        .then(() => book.save())  // The chain takes on the state of the promise
                                  // returned by `book.save`
        .then(data => {
            hook.onSuccess(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            hook.onError(error);
        });
}
```

In that, I'm assuming `createBookFromRequest` and `checkBookData` are both synchronous processes, as that's how you're using them.

And actually, given that's the case, I don't see any need for the promise you're creating to verify the data. So it could be simpler:

```
createBook(data, hook) {
    let book = createBookFromRequest(data);
    if (checkBookData(book)) {
        book.save()
            .then(_ => hook.onSuccess(data))
            .catch(error => hook.onError(error));
    } else {
        hook.onError("Invalid data");
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer! Just want to chip in with a comment that the `verifyData.then(() => book.save())` can be rewritten as `verifyData.then(book.save).then(...)`, though I'm quite sure you intentionally omitted that to make the example more clear! But, could always be useful to know for the OP! :)

Comment: @DanielB: Probably not: `.then(book.save)` will call `book.save` with `this` set to `undefined` during the call. But presumably it needs `this` set to `book`. The other option is `.then(book.save.bind(book))` but I find the arrow function clearer. (`bind` is useful for if you want to avoid creating the closure, though.)

Comment: Doh, of course! I read the code too quick there, never realising it wasn't a save function taking the resolved book as an argument! Thanks T.J!

Comment: @DanielB: Sorry, forgot to say "thanks" above for the compliment on the answer! (I focussed too much on the `then` thing. :-) )